# boost::icl::interval_map union on overlap

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to make [interval_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost/icl/interval_map.html) with following accumulative behavior:

```
[1..3]->1 +
[2..4]->2 +
[5..7]->3 +
[6..8]->4
=
[1..4]->{1,2}, [5..8]->{3,4}
+
[3..6]->42
=
[1..8]->{1,2,3,4,42}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've struggled with a very similar question before and couldn't find a library-supported way.

> **PS**. Found that post [boost::multi_index_container, operations on std::set inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036817/boostmulti-index-container-operations-on-stdset-inside-container/44047013#44047013)
>
> It's interesting to compare because it basically does similar interval-consolidating but at the time of query. This has benefits (it retains insertion history so you can query other results that benefit from non-lossy storage). It also trades insertion efficiency for more query cost.

I'd probably write the insertion/combination operation myself.

I've tried to come up with a descriptive name here. Since the operation feels similar to landing "drops" into bigger "pools", I called the operation `mix`:

```
template <typename Map, typename V = typename Map::segment_type>
void mix(Map& m, std::initializer_list<V> drops) {
    typename Map::codomain_combine combine;

    for (auto drop : drops) {
        // combine with all overlapping existing segments
        auto range = m.equal_range(drop.first);

        for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
            combine(drop.second, it->second);
            drop.first = hull(drop.first, it->first);
        }

        m.set(drop); // logically equivalent to m.add(drop) here
    }
}
```

With this you can articulate your desired behaviour like so:

```
int main() {
    using Map      = boost::icl::interval_map<int, Ints>;
    using Interval = Map::interval_type::type;
    Map m;

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    mix(m, { {Interval::closed(1,3), {1}},
             {Interval::closed(2,4), {2}},
             {Interval::closed(5,7), {3}},
             {Interval::closed(6,8), {4}} });

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    mix(m, { {Interval::closed(3,6), {42}} }); 

    std::cout << m << "\n";
}
```

And the output will be

```
{}
{([1,4]->{1,2,})([5,8]->{3,4,})}
{([1,8]->{1,2,3,4,42,})}
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2d9ddbd697ec811)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Map, typename V = typename Map::segment_type>
void mix(Map& m, std::initializer_list<V> drops) {
    typename Map::codomain_combine combine;

    for (auto drop : drops) {
        // combine with all overlapping existing segments
        auto range = m.equal_range(drop.first);

        for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
            combine(drop.second, it->second);
            drop.first = hull(drop.first, it->first);
        }

        m.set(drop); // logically equivalent to m.add(drop) here
    }
}

// For debug: an ostreamable std::set<int>
struct Ints : std::set<int> {
    using std::set<int>::set;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ints const& s) {
        os << '{';
        for(auto i : s) os << i << ",";
        return os << '}';
    }
};

int main() {
    using Map      = boost::icl::interval_map<int, Ints>;
    using Interval = Map::interval_type::type;
    Map m;

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    mix(m, { {Interval::closed(1,3), {1}},
             {Interval::closed(2,4), {2}},
             {Interval::closed(5,7), {3}},
             {Interval::closed(6,8), {4}} });

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    mix(m, { {Interval::closed(3,6), {42}} }); 

    std::cout << m << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I've just found that older answer where similar functionality was desired: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036817/boostmulti-index-container-operations-on-stdset-inside-container/44047013#44047013 Here, the combining is being done at the time of query, instead of at the time of insert. Just for comparison, could be interesting.